# Who are the top two actors whose movies have a median rating >= 8?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT n.name as actor_name , COUNT(r.movie_id) as movie_count
FROM names as n
INNER JOIN director_mapping as dm
ON n.id = dm.movie_id
INNER JOIN movie as m
ON dm.movie_id = m.id
INNER JOIN ratings as r
ON m.id = r.movie_id
WHERE r.median_rating >= 8 
GROUP BY actor_name
ORDER BY movie_count DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

It gives nothing in result, could anyone please help?

[image: ERD]

Comment: Use `role_mapping` and not `director_mapping`

Comment: No luck! It still doesn't give me output.

Comment: Please provide us an example db schema, data and expected result at sqlfiddle.com to be able to try our solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join on `director_mapping` was wrong and the column you joined on too:

```
SELECT n.name as actor_name , COUNT(r.movie_id) as movie_count
FROM names as n
INNER JOIN role_mapping as rm ON n.id = rm.name_id
INNER JOIN movie as m ON m.id = rm.movie_id
INNER JOIN ratings as r ON m.id = r.movie_id
WHERE r.median_rating >= 8 
GROUP BY actor_name
ORDER BY movie_count DESC
LIMIT 2;
```